# How do you prevent one piece of clothing from passing through another?

Tags: cloth-simulation

So I'm trying to create a jacket for my character here. I want it to be a jean jacket so I imagine it needs some stiffness, but that's not what I'm here for. As you can see, the results are disastrous. I'm new to this so I wouldn't be surprised if the problem is my jacket has bad topology or something. But I got the teal shirt to fit pretty well and I applied the same physics data for it to the jacket. Here's all the information I can give:

The character has a collision property applied to it, so I don't know why the sleeves aren't wrapping around the arms. I applied a cloth and collision property to the teal shirt thinking it would keep the jacket from passing through it. I included a screenshot of the jacket's physics properties if that helps.

Can anyone identify the problem from what I've provided?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: In your screenshots it looks like you start off with shirt and jacket not fitted to the body. So do you simulate your pieces of clothing both at the same time to fit to the body? Could it be there's some "rivaling" between those two pieces? Have you tried fitting the jacket  directly onto the body without the shirt? Have you tried fitting the shirt first and applying the softbody, and then fit the jacket afterwards?

Comment: I was testing them both at the same time. Is that not a good way to do it? Btw update: I just tried the jacket while having the shirt hidden and the results were the same.